# What is node's equivalent of Perl's magic `tie()` mechanism (hooking into/intercepting access to variables)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for something like this example, intercepting access to string, array and object variables with user-defined callbacks/hooks:

```js
var foo = [];
tie( // hypothetical
    foo,
    {
        STORE: // callback triggered when assigning: foo[index] = value
        function(self, index, value) {
            if (value.match('fnord')) {
                self[index] = "Nothing to see here. Move along.";
                return;
            }
            self[index] = value;
        },
        FETCH: // callback triggered when accessing: foo[index]
        function(self, index) {
            if (42 == index) {
                return "This is The Answer.";
            }
            return self[index];
        }
    }
);
```

---

Simple demo of a working implementation of that concept:

```perl
package Quux;
use Tie::Array ();
use base 'Tie::StdArray';
sub FETCH {
    my ($self, $index) = @_;
    return 'This is The Answer.' if 42 == $index;
    return $self->[$index];
}
sub STORE {
    my ($self, $index, $value) = @_;
    if ($value =~ 'fnord') {
        $self->[$index] = 'Nothing to see here. Move along.';
        return;
    }
    $self->[$index] = $value;
}

package main;
tie my @foo, 'Quux';
@foo = (undef) x 50;
print $foo[42];
$foo[0] = 'fnord';
print $foo[0];
```

full documentation: [tie](http://p3rl.org/perltie) (concept), [`tie()`](http://p3rl.org/tie) (function), [Tie::Array](http://p3rl.org/Tie::StdArray), [magic](http://p3rl.org/guts#Magic-Virtual-Tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough equivalent to this functionality is [the Proxy API](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies). This is an ES6 feature, but V8 already provides "experimental" support for it (start node with `--harmony` or `--harmony-proxies` to enable this feature). Here's your snippet rewritten with proxies:

```
var foo = (function() {

    var obj = {};
    return Proxy.create({
        set: function(self, index, value) {
            if (value.match(/fnord/)) {
                obj[index] = "Nothing to see here. Move along.";
                return;
            }
            obj[index] = value;
        },
        get: function(self, index) {
            if (42 == index) {
                return "This is The Answer.";
            }
            return obj[index];
        }
    });

})();

console.log(foo[42]);
foo[0] = 'fnord';
console.log(foo[0]);
```